# Rails 4 setting default_timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Could i set the default_timezone in gmt+n, or somethink like that?Now i have

```
  class Application < Rails::Application
  config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Kyiv'   # "Europe/Kiev"
```

and it returns

```
  can't convert nil into an exact number
```

when the time methods is called (i also restarted my server).

Comment: In `applicaton.rb` add this line `config.time_zone = 'Kyiv'` and all time will be shown in time zone `Kyiv`

Answer (score 0):

You might be setting an invalid value.

Call `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map` and look at the return value. You'll find all the supported time zone names.

Comment: <TZInfo::TimezoneProxy: Europe/Helsinki>,                  @current_period=nil>, "**Kyiv**"=>#<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x43bc9d8 @name="**Kyiv**", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this is the right way.

```
class ApplicationController < ApplicationController :: Base

before_filter :set_time_zone

def set_time_zone
  Time.zone = "kyiv"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my config, but notice that the timezone I wanted the application to run in (Brazil Time) is different from the Timezone in which the app was host (Heroku time, which is something else).

```
  class Application < Rails::Application

    config.time_zone = 'Brasilia'
    # config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Brasilia'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    #config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    config.i18n.available_locales = [:en, :"pt_BR"]
    config.i18n.locale = [:"pt_BR"]
    config.i18n.default_locale = :"pt_BR"

 end
```